# SPARQL if and filtering combination

Tags: sparql

I want to make a question. I have a sparql query and I want to use (in where clause) filtering only under specific conditions. For example,

I want to say:

```
SELECT ?country, ?department 
WHERE 
{
IF (?country="USA", FILTER (?department= "Logistics") ).
If (?country="UK", FILTER (?department= "Marketing") ). 
}
```

I hope that you understood what I want to achieve.
Thank you.

Comment: The rest of the SPARQL query is missing, and without the triple patterns it's hard to help. It is not clear what you want to achieve, in its current form you bind both values. Please provide a full example also with some sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the need for IF here but I'm just guessing a solution since your query is rather incomplete:

```sql
SELECT * WHERE {
  ?s :country ?country .
  ?s :department ?department .
  VALUES (?country ?department) {
     ( "USA"  "Logistics" )
     ( "UK"  "Marketing" )
  }
}
```

Comment: yeah but how do I insert a filter function within an if statement ?

Comment: @Evan would be good if you open a new question, I need the query and context. Basically `BIND(IF(condition, value1, value2)  AS ?filterTerm) FILTER(?x = ?filterTerm)` or something